# Opening image with PIL with tf.data

Tags: python, tensorflow

I'm currently trying to use tf.data to load VOC2012 dataset for semantic segmentation.  The labels in VOC2012 uses colour map, which would be automatically converted if I use PIL library.  This is not the case when I invoke tf.read_file.

```
from PIL import Image

train_data = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((img_filename_list, lbl_filename_list))

def preprocessing(img_filename, lbl_filename):
    # Load image
    train_img = tf.read_file(img_path + img_filename)
    train_img = tf.image.decode_jpeg(train_img, channels=3)
    train_img = train_img / 255.0  # Normalize

    return train_img, lbl_filename

train_data = train_data.map(preprocessing).shuffle(100).repeat().batch(2)
iterator = train_data.make_initializable_iterator()
next_element = iterator.get_next()
training_init_op = iterator.make_initializer(train_data)

with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(training_init_op)
    while True:
        train_images, lbl_filename = sess.run(next_element)
```

This is what I'm doing right now, although ideally, I want the preprocessing function to return a label image loaded using PIL so I can create one-hot vectors.

```
def preprocessing(img_filename, lbl_filename):
    ...# Load train images
    train_lbl = Image.open(lbl_path + lbl_filename)
    ...# Do some other stuff
    return train_img, train_lbl
```

This would give an error

```
AttributeError: 'Tensor' object has no attribute 'read'
```

Is there any solution to this?

Comment: You could use `tf.py_func` to define a function that operates on `numpy` arrays and uses python code on them. If you take as input te string, load the image via PIL and return it via `np.asarray(pil_img)` it should work

Comment: On the other hand, you cold also look into the [TF object detection API repository](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/research/object_detection) for functions handling the VOC dataset (since it's a standard dataset, the likelihood that you'll find what you need in there is quite high)

Comment: @GPhilo thank you, I ended up using tf.py_func to solve the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As suggested by @GPhilo, using the tf.py_func would solve this problem.
Here's my solution code

```
def read_labels(lbl_filename):
    train_lbl = Image.open(lbl_path + lbl_filename.decode("utf-8"))
    train_lbl = np.asarray(train_lbl)
    return train_lbl

def preprocessing(img_filename, lbl_filename):
    train_lbl = tf.py_func(read_labels, [lbl_filename], tf.uint8)
```